# Issue manually deploying web package built in VSTS

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment

We have moved to VSTS in azure, with local builds.

I have a asp.net mvc web application which I have create a build for which creates a web deploy package using the following parameters

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true  
/p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False
```

We then have releases which deploy to different environments e.g. DEV, QAL and TST. Works nicely all the parameters in the web.config are modified according to the parameters.xml file.

Now comes the issue, we do not do automatic releases to production. So I take the web deploy package with the setparameters.xml file modified to meet the required configuration and other files and manually do in import into our IIS site. It completes but with these type of errors

```
25/08/2017 2:58:50 PM] Parameter entry 'wordAutomation_EndPoint/1' is applicable to 'C:\agent2\_work\6\s\Main\Clients\Web\WebUI\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config' because of its scope.
[25/08/2017 2:58:50 PM] Parameter entry 'wordAutomation_EndPoint/1' could not be applied to 'C:\agent2\_work\6\s\Main\Clients\Web\WebUI\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config'. Deployment will continue with the original data. Details:
No matches were found for the search string '/configuration/system.servicemodel/client/endpoint[@name='WordAutomationBasicHttpEndpoint']/@address' (type 'XmlFile').
```

So none of the parameters in the SetParameters.xml file are transformed into the web.config file.

So currently I have a web deploy package which will deploy to IIS using the release task WinRM - IIS Web App Deployment, with no special parameters, but I cannot deploy the same package manually.

Any ideas?

Simon

Comment: Is there section match /configuration/system.servicemodel/client/endpoint[@name='WordAutomationBasicHttpEndpoint']/@address? What do you want to change? Could you provide the sample to explain it? You can share a simple project on the OneDrive too. On the other hand, there are Web Deploy Parameter file and Override Parameters settings in IIS Web App Deployment task.

Comment: I have been doing some more testing and the build parameters make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Have been doing some testing and the build parameters have no bearing on the issue.

I have created a bare bones ASP.Net Web Application, added an appSettings to the web.config (testKey)

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="testKey" value="testValue" />
  </appSettings>
```

I then added a parameters.xml file

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="testKey" defaultValue="123">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="Web.config"
                    match="/configuration/appsettings/add[@key='testKey']/@value" 
                    />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

Publish the app to a web deployment package (.zip) on my c drive. The setparameters.xml file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Test" />
  <setParameter name="testKey" value="123" />
</parameters>
```

Then manually deploying I right click on our IIS site, click Deploy/Import Application, accept all defaults and then I get the following warnings and errors

> [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/1'
> is applicable to
> 'iisApp/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/2' is applicable to
> 'setAcl/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/2' is applicable to
> 'setAcl/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Performing synchronization pass
>
> ## 1. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/1' is applicable to
>
> 'iisApp/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/2' is applicable to
> 'setAcl/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/2' is applicable to
> 'setAcl/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/1' is applicable to
> 'iisApp/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/2' is applicable to
> 'setAcl/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/2' is applicable to
> 'setAcl/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/1' is applicable to
> 'iisApp/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/2' is applicable to
> 'setAcl/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/2' is applicable to
> 'setAcl/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] No backup was executed.
> [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/1'
> is applicable to
> 'iisApp/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/2' is applicable to
> 'setAcl/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/2' is applicable to
> 'setAcl/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Source createApp
> (C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp) does not match
> destination (DefaultWebsite/Test) differing in attributes
> (isDest['False','True']). Update pending. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM]
> Update operation on createApp
> (C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp) skipped
> because of rule ApplicationExistsRule. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Source
> filePath
> (C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\parameters.xml)
> does not match destination (DefaultWebsite/Test\parameters.xml)
> differing in attributes (size['306','340'],lastWriteTime['08/29/2017
> 03:42:50','08/29/2017 03:34:38']). Update pending. [29/08/2017 1:13:56
> PM] Updating file (DefaultWebsite/Test\parameters.xml). [29/08/2017
> 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'testName/1' is applicable to
> 'C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Web.config'
> because of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry
> 'testName/1' could not be applied to
> 'C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Web.config'.
> Deployment will continue with the original data. Details: No matches
> were found for the search string
> '/configuration/appsettings/add[@name='testKey']/@value' (type
> 'XmlFile'). [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Attribute 'size' equality changed
> to False when comparing filePath
> (DefaultWebsite/Test\Views\Web.config) to
> C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Web.config
> because of rule Parameterization. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Source
> filePath
> (C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Web.config)
> does not match destination (DefaultWebsite/Test\Views\Web.config)
> differing in attributes (parameters). Update pending. [29/08/2017
> 1:13:56 PM] Source filePath
> (C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Web.config)
> replaced with changed attributes (size['1925','1924']) because of rule
> Parameterization. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Updating file
> (DefaultWebsite/Test\Views\Web.config). [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM]
> Parameter entry 'testName/1' is applicable to
> 'C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config'
> because of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry
> 'testName/1' could not be applied to
> 'C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config'.
> Deployment will continue with the original data. Details: No matches
> were found for the search string
> '/configuration/appsettings/add[@name='testKey']/@value' (type
> 'XmlFile'). [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Source setAcl
> (C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp) does not match
> destination (DefaultWebsite/Test) differing in attributes
> (isDest['False','True'],setAclUser,setAclAccess). Update pending.
> [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Adding ACL's for path (DefaultWebsite/Test)
> [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Source setAcl
> (C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp) does not match
> destination (DefaultWebsite/Test) differing in attributes
> (isDest['False','True'],setAclUser,setAclAccess). Update pending.
> [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Adding ACL's for path (DefaultWebsite/Test)
> [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] The dependency check 'DependencyCheckInUse'
> found no issues. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/1' is applicable to
> 'iisApp/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/2' is applicable to
> 'setAcl/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] Parameter entry 'IIS Web
> Application Name/2' is applicable to
> 'setAcl/C:\temp\test\test\test\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp' because
> of its scope. [29/08/2017 1:13:56 PM] The synchronization completed in
> 1 pass(es).

The site deploys but the web.config is not updated with the values in the SetParameters.xml file. So the value for testKey should be 123.

I think its something to do with the scope, but bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply but I had the same issue, the value wasn't being updated in my web.config.

Turns out my issue was due to case sensitivity in the match string. Where you have:

> match="/configuration/appsettings/add[@key='testKey']/@value"

it should be:

match="/configuration/app**S**ettings/add[@key='testKey']/@value"

Notice the capital 's' in `appSettings`.

That's what got it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that this problem happens (or at least was happening to me) because the web.config had an XML schema definition parameter in the  `<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.Netconfiguration/V2.0">` tag , removing this XMLNS parameter so it was just `<configuration>` fixed the problem.